# Javascript countdown clock with auto restart

Tags: javascript, clock, restart, countdown

What i need is a javascript countdown clock that will start everyday at 7:40am and end at 2:15pm. But when it ends at 2:15pm i need it to auto restart at 7:40 am.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question instead of asking for the entire thing to be written for you?

Comment: awesome, have fun writing your program!

Comment: "auto restart". You mean if you have a page opened for a full day it does that automatically?

Comment: No i cant ask for a more specific question because i do not know how to code in jscript.

Comment: Here's some pseudocode: `var countdownClock = function() { /* implementation goes here */ };  countdownClock();`

Comment: *No i cant ask for a more specific question because i do not know how to code in jscript.* Then hire someone who can.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

// 6 hours and 45 minutes
iMilliseconds = 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 45 * 60 * 1000;

function Restart()
{
 Start();
 setTimeout(iMilliseconds, Restart);
}


function Start()
{
 // Do things
}

$(document).ready(function()
 {
 Restart(); 
});
```